# Erro Cordova/Phonegap - Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova, phonegap-buillder

Criei um novo projeto cordova e adicionei a plataforma android normalmente como já havia feito antes, porem quando eu executo o comando `cordova build`ou `cordova run`ele da este erro não consegui encontrar a solução.

Alguem sabe o que devo fazer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: utilize esses dois comandos:
`cordova platform remove android`
e
`cordova platform add android`

recompile com:
`cordova build android` e veja o que acontece.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver simplesmente atualizei o SDK e voltou a funcionar, valeu pela ajuda galera.

Comment: @jbueno mas acho que ninguém tinha respondido isso, não?

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver tentando executar na plataforma android, você deve ter as seguintes variaveis de ambiente configuradas no computador:
ANDROID_SDK
ANDROID_NDK
ANDROID_HOME
ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS
e também colocar no PATH

Caso as variáveis estejam configuradas e ainda esteja com erro, você pode executar os seguintes comandos:
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android

Comment: Eu tenho criada a PATH e a ANDROID_HOME, qual seria o conteudo das outras? @henriquels

Comment: ANDROID_SDK="/opt/software/android-sdk"
ANDROID_NDK="/opt/software/android-ndk"
ANDROID_HOME="$ANDROID_SDK"
ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools"
PATH="${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS"

Answer (score 0):

Bom, Eu não utilizo o Phonegap/cordova deste jeito, Eu sempre testo no meu emulador dele mesmo

> http://app.phonegap.com/

Mas vamos la, você pode Tentar excluir seu `.gradle` de

> C:  \ Users \ diretório

e tente novamente.

Ou:

Em Eclipse, vá para Windows -> Preferências -> gradle-> argumentos. Encontre Argumentos JVM escolher opção "USE:" e escrever estes argumentos -Xms128m -Xmx512m e clique Aplicar.

E por ultimo, isso é só uma dica, não tem nada a ver com o erro, atualize seu Java.

Comment: Eu já deletei o arquivo `.gradle` e não deu certo, não utilizo o eclipse para o desenvolvimento, desenvolvo utilizando o Sublime, estou baixando a nova versão do Java.